# Loop through subfolders and run

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'd like to use the following script to cycle through all the subfolders in /Volumes/Volume-B/Exchange and apply these ACL and permissions changes, but not apply them to the /Volumes/Volume-B/Exchange parent folder.

Some sort of loop that cycles through the subfolders is where I'm stuck...

Suggestions on how to implement this cleanly much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH
DEST=/Volumes/Volume-B/Exchange
LOG=/var/log/fixperms-exchange.log


{
echo ""
echo "Begin Fixing perms on $DEST at `date`"
chmod -R +a "studiostaff allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" "$DEST"
chmod -R +a "studiostaff inherited allow read,write,execute,delete,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity" "$DEST"

chown -R padmin:staff "$DEST"
echo "Permissions fix complete at `date`"
echo ""

} >> $LOG 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple for-loop:

```
for DIR in $DEST/*
do
    chmod -R +a ... $DIR
done
```

That should not change any permissions on `DEST` itself, only its children.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to cycle through files**. Applying ACL's to a file hierarchy recursively is as simple as using `find` :

```
# Export environment variable
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH

# Initialise timestamp & variables
dest=/Volumes/Volume-B/Exchange
serv_log=/var/log/fixperms-exchange.service.log
ts=$(date +%T_+%F);

# About to fix permissions
echo '[$ts] : about to fix permissions' >> $serv_log;

# Find all sub directories of parent and chown/chmod -R

find $dest/*  -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec chown -R padmin:staff {} \; -exec chmod -R +a "studiostaff allow list,..." {} \; -exec chmod -R +a "studiostaff allow read,..." {} \;

# Finished fixing permissions
echo '[$ts] : completed permissions task' >> $serv_log;
```

`find` locates all the direct subdirectories of `$dest` (`-type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`),. `-exec utility [argument ...] {}` (`man find`) is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility. Works fine with filenames that have NUL characters in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without a loop as follows:

```
chmod -R +a "..." /Volumes/Volume-B/Exchange/*
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
DEST='/Volumes/Volume-B/Exchange/*'
```

This together with the -R switch should apply all the changes to contents of the parent directory.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work -- I should have mentioned I tried that already...I believe the chmod command needs the name of the folder in question its changing permissions on...